# Deploy asp.net mvc web application on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, iis-6

I have develop an asp.net MVC 2 web application. I want to deploy its published version on my server (local office server). It has been set up with Windows 2003 server and IIS 6.0 version.

I went through [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/) link
, I followed the option 1) but unfortunately could not succeed. Other option seems impossible for me for now.

What do I have to do here? please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open IIS Manager
2. Right click on “Web Sites” folder
3. Hit New -> Web Site…
4. In the wizard hit Next
5. Add Description, hit next
6. Assign IP, Port and Host header, hit next
7. Enter/Browse path to the website deployment folder, hit next
8. Select Read, Run Scripts and Write, hit next, hit finish
9. Right click the newly added website, hit properties
10. In the properties window go to “Home Directory” tab
11. Click the “Configuration…” button
12. In the popup window on the “Mappings” tab locate the .aspx extension in the “Application extensions” grid, select it and hit the “Edit…” button (this is just to copy the location of the aspx mapping)
13. In the edit window copy the executable path, hit cancel
14. Back in the Application Configuration screen hit the “Insert…” button
15. Paste the executable path
16. Uncheck “Verify that file exists”, hit OK
17. Hit OK in the Application Configuration window
18. Back in the properties window go to the ASP.NET tab
19. In the “ASP.NET version” dropdown select 4.0.xxxxx, hit Apply

Answer (score 0):

Phil Haack also [blogged about this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) and if you are using ASP.NET 4.0 make sure to read his [updated post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/12/22/asp-net-mvc-3-extensionless-urls-on-iis-6.aspx). Follow the step by step tutorial and you should be able to get this working.